Query with 3 tables, cartesian product warning
My database contains a fixed amount of recordings and each user must rate each recording (each individual rating is stored in the ratings table).

I'm trying to write an SQLAlchemy query that returns all users who haven't rated all recordings. I have 4 recordings with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4 and 4 users with IDs 1, 2, 3, 4 and the following ratings:
{user_id: 1, recording_id: 1} {user_id: 1, recording_id: 2} {user_id: 1, recording_id: 3} {user_id: 1, recording_id: 4}
{user_id: 2, recording_id: 1} {user_id: 2, recording_id: 3} {user_id: 2, recording_id: 4}
{user_id: 4, recording_id: 1} {user_id: 4, recording_id: 2} {user_id: 4, recording_id: 3} {user_id: 4, recording_id: 4}

I want my query to return the users with IDs 2 and 3 (as user 2 hasn't rated recording 2 and user 3 hasn't rated a single recording). I thought I could achieve this by filtering the users by recordings that don't appear in the ratings for that specific user:
results = session.query(User).filter(
        ~Recording.id.in_(
            select(Rating.recording_id).where(Rating.user_id == User.id)
            )
        ).all()

It seems to work but I get a warning:
SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "recordings" and FROM element "users".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.
  ).all()

I tried to join the tables at the beginning of the query session.query(User).join(Rating).join(Recording).filter but then the program doesn't run because of an error:

Select statement returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate() to control correlation manually

How do I solve this issue?

maybe you should start with rating and join user and join records. But I would first use rating to count how many ratings has every user and get users which don't have correct number of ratings - something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rating GROUP BY user_id - don't remember if it can use HAVING

Thanks for the answer!
The problem with comparing only the numbers is that if one of the recordings was replaced, I would like the users to rate the new rating (which would have a different ID), so I need to check for the missing recording IDs in the ratings.
I'll try to change the join order and let you know!

Either way the query is wrong. The query filters only for users who haven't rated any recording, not those who haven't rated all recordings. I don't know sqlalchemy syntax, but SQL is something like SELECT * FROM users u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM recordings rd LEFT JOIN ratings r ON r.recording_id = rd.id AND r.user_id = u.id HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(r.recording_id)) It's basically Relational Division Without Remainder.

Thanks @Charlieface for the SQL query, I'll try and translate that to SQLAlchemy!
I don't think  the previous query filters only for users who haven't rated any recording tho: the ~ before Recording.id.in_ is a negation: it filters users for which there is at least one recording that doesn't appear in the ratings recording_id : that is users who hasn't rated all recordings.

Ah I see, a double NOT EXISTS. Yes that's another more obvious option, if normally less efficient.

I twisted your solution around mine and ended up getting something that works. The following sqlalchemy correctly filters the users table and throws no warning:
user_ratings_subquery = select(Recording.id).join(Rating, and_(Rating.user_id == User.id, Rating.recording_id == Recording.id))     unrated_recordings_subquery = select(Recording.id).exists().where(Recording.id.not_in(user_ratings_subquery))     results = session.query(User).filter(unrated_recordings_subquery).all()

You know the amount of recordings, so you have to search users with less amount of ratings. Easy SQL query.

Sure, but what if one recording gets replaced? The amount remains the same, but I want users to rate the new recording whatsoever.
